# Woocommerce - Get global attribute data

Tags: woocommerce

On my woocommerce site, I currently have a set of 'attuributes' aligned with each product.

Currently I call them 'Seller' and 'Contact Details'

[image: additional Information]

What I'm hoping to do is display this information on any emails that the customer receives, below where the order information normally displays.

This information will be different for each product, but titled the same, as I've added these two things as global attributes

[image]

What code would I have to add to my custom email to display this information?

Thanks.